# SVG image not displaying after uploading to FTP

Tags: object, svg

Chrome will display the .svg logo when I view the page locally but after I upload the page to the FTP the image wont render...

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-16" id="top">
  <div class="grid-16 beta fixed" div id="header">
    <object class="intro" data="images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Aengus Tukel" />
    </object>
    <a href="#aboutcontact" class="center uppercase smoothScroll"><p>about/contact</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: probably not the problem, but `“”` are NOT valid html attribute quotes. Don't use a word processor to edit your HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after I posted.